# Conditional Logging in Log4J

Tags: java, log4j

I have a Java Maven project which contains 3 modules, say: A, B, C.

```
-----pom.xml
  |
  |--A
  |
  |--B
  |
  |--C
```

Module C is a library that is used by both A and B.

Inside module C, there are some log4j logging lines like:

```
  log.info("My log here");
```

This log will be produced if the method that contains it is called.

However, I want to be able to configure log4j so that these logs are only produced by module A but not module B.

Is this something possible?